# Rpy2 'show' not found on httpd using wsgi

Tags: django, wsgi, rpy2

Everything works fine on development server. However, the following error was showing when I moved the project to the production server running httpd and wsgi.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught LookupError while rendering: 'show' not found

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://10.14.5.18/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught LookupError while rendering: 'show' not found

Exception Location:     /usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py in RObjectMixin, line 22
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:    

['/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_pagination-1.0.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/srv/www/foodborn.project/']

Server time:    Thu, 23 Feb 2012 13:12:48 -0600
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

**Update**
Track down to the Apache error log found something like "bytecode mismatch". Google found that it related to R. So recompile R solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`TemplateSyntaxError` tells you that there's something that Django/Python doesn't like in your template file. Do you have something like `{% ...show... %}` in your template? Find your template and search for the word "show" it is trying to render the template and it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Thanks. We know "show" is related to RPy2. But just do not understand why something is wrong in production and everything is fine in develop environment. They are using the same Python, R and Rpy2.